# Re-Using JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Creating a cake ordering form, and the # of cakes available can vary from month to month.  I am attempting to tweak a JS function created from @Anderson Contreira but in my fiddle it does not work.  Here is what I have thus far - 
Why does nothing change when I enter a quantity?

https://jsfiddle.net/2uack1w6/

Syntax
**JS**

```
    function calculate(el){
    var quantity = el.val();
    var id = el.attr("id").replace("item_","").replace("_qty","");
    var data = {quantity: quantity,id:id};
    var targetTax = $("#item_"+id+"_tax");
    var targetTotalPrice = $("#item_"+id+"_totalprice");
    $.post($.post(window.alert("It's been one or two or three entered");
    });
}
var qty = $("#item_1_qty");
var qty1 = $("#item_2_qty");
var qty2 = $("#item_3_qty");
qty.on("keyup",function(){
    window.alert("It's been one or two or three entered");
});
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div id="Form1" runat="server">
    <table id="table1" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="lblChoccake">Choc Cake</label></td>
            <td><label for="lblitem1price">$25.00</label></td>
            <td><input  type="text" id="item_1_qty" name="txtitem1qty" value="0" maxlength="10" size="3"></td>
            <td><input  type ="text" id="item_1_tax" name="txtitem1tax" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly></td>
            <td><input  type="text" id="item_1_totalprice" name="txtitem1totalprice" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="lblLemonFudgecake">Lemon Fudge Cake</label></td>
            <td><label for="lblitem2price">$15.00</label></td>
            <td><input  type="text" id="item_2_qty" name="txtitem1qty" value="0" maxlength="10" size="3"></td>
            <td><input  type ="text" id="item_2_tax" name="txtitem1tax" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly></td>
            <td><input  type="text" id="item_2_totalprice" name="txtitem1totalprice" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="lblCoconut">Coconut Cake</label></td>
            <td><label for="lblitem3price">$35.00</label></td>
            <td><input  type="text" id="item_3_qty" name="txtitem1qty" value="0" maxlength="10" size="3"></td>
            <td><input  type ="text" id="item_3_tax" name="txtitem1tax" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly></td>
            <td><input  type="text" id="item_3_totalprice" name="txtitem1totalprice" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `calculate()` anywhere. And your fiddle doesn't work because it doesn't include jQuery - try this version: https://jsfiddle.net/2uack1w6/1/ (although even then the keyup handler only applies to the first quantity field).

Comment: @nnnnnn I believe OP is referring to the alert function not working but you're right. This should be mentioned in the question

Comment: @nnnnnn - this will only display a prompt if a qty is entered for the 1st item, it ignores for the subsequent ones.

Comment: Yes. Because *that is what you've coded*. You only call `.on()` on the first item. You could say `$("#item_1_qty,#item_1_qty,#item_1_qty").on(...);`. If the `calculate()` function is unrelated to what you're asking about then please [edit] your question to not show it.

Comment: @nnnnnn - oh you are accurate, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var qty = $("#item_1_qty");
  var qty1 = $("#item_2_qty");
  var qty2 = $("#item_3_qty");

  qty.on("keyup",function(){
    alert("It's been one or two or three entered");
  });
});
```

Try this, you are assigning variables before the document has actually loaded.

Comment: You're missing the closing `)` on the `.on()` and the closing `})` on `jQuery()` (and missing whitespace...)

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks, I am on a mobile device I'll edit it once I can access my computer. Thanks for reviewing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/andersoncontreira/mtu6syby/1/

You can make some changes and will work well:

Add a class in each input of item_?_qty e.g.: `<input type="text" id="item_1_qty" class="item_qty" />`

In your javascript, you can leave the call generic:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //you can use a class for help you
    $(".item_qty").on("keyup",function(){
    //window.alert("It's been one or two or three entered");
    calculate($(this));
    });
});
```